# Get selected index of dropdown from array Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am saving all inputs in a form in the form of array into a variable.

Example: `var data = $('inputs,select')`

Now, I want to get selected index of dropdown using variable data.

Please help.

Edit: Added Fiddle for reference

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dk32v3q4/)

Comment: Can you please show, what have you tried till now?

Comment: Please find my updated question, I have added fiddle @PrerakSola

Comment: `$('inputs,select')` or `$('input,select')`? You can get the `selectedIndex` property using `prop` method:  `data.filter('select').prop('selectedIndex');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood your question properly, you save a jQuery object with every input and select in a variable­. To get the selected index of a dropdown you would have to iterate over your variable to find out if its a select or a regular input, and then get its selected index.

```
//loop over every dom element in the variable
data.each(function () {
    //if its a select 
    if ($(this).is("select")) {
        //find its selected index using native DOM and do something with it
        $(this)[0].selectedIndex;
    }
});
```

Comment: OMG!! Awesome... Thanks for the Idea. Ideally "$(data)[4].selectedIndex", only this statement worked... cheers

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to add `$( "select option:selected" ).text();` to select the selected item.

This was from: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-get-the-text-value-of-a-selected-option/